# Assign separate entrypoint scripts to separate HtmlWebpackPlugin instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Given an entry/output like

```
entry: {
    app: 'src/client/app.js',
    unauthApp.js: 'src/client/unauth.js'
  },
output: {
  path: 'dist',
  filename: 'scripts/[name]-[chunkhash].js'
},
...
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'views/index.html'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'views/index-inauth.html'
  })
]
```

is it possible using two instances of [`HtmlWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to put the `app` script into one template and the `unauthApp` script into the other. So far all I have been able to do is put both scripts in both. I'm also playing with using `htmlWebpackTemplate` so perhaps there is an option there I have not seen.

`webpack@^4.6.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `chunks` field? It `Allows you to add only some chunks (e.g only the unit-test chunk)`

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'views/index.html',
    chunks: ['app'],
    inject: true
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'views/index-unauth.html',
    chunks: ['unauthApp.js'],
    inject: true
  })
]
```