# webpack 4 - split chunks plugin for multiple entries

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, code-splitting

Using [split chunks plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) with the following config :

```
{
    entry: {
        entry1: [entry1.js],
        entry2: [entry2.js],
        entry3: [entry3.js],
        ...
    }
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    } 
}
```

The code would get perfectly split into:

```
vendors-entry1-entry2-entry3.js // common for all
vendors-entry1-entry3.js // vendors only required by both entry1, entry3
entry1-entry2.js // common code of entry1 and entry2
entry1.js // unique entry's code
entry2.js
entry3.js
```

Question is, **how do i now use the specific vendors per entry in my html (or ejs in my specific case)**?

Using [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) as recommended would simply create an index.html which loads all of the above, although the use case is clearly:

When rendering **entry1** page - load:

```
vendors-entry1-entry2-entry3.js
vendors-entry1-entry3.js
entry1-entry2.js
entry1.js
```

When rendering **entry2** page - load:

```
vendors-entry1-entry2-entry3.js
entry1-entry2.js
entry2.js
```

etc..

Comment: @Raviteja `CommonsChunkPlugin` has been removed in webpack 4. `SplitChunksPlugin` is it's successor.

Comment: Please explain the downvotes, I'd like to know if i'm missing a very basic thing here..

Comment: seems duplicated to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163019/assign-separate-entrypoint-scripts-to-separate-htmlwebpackplugin-instances/50166110#50166110

Comment: @loveky I don't know the chunk names since they're auto-generated

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: Daniel or @A. Matías Quezada I am curious if you ever found a solution.  Having a similar issue and info on splitChunks with multiple entrypoints is very hard to come by.

Comment: @tarponjargon unfortunately not yet.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming this question to "WebPack 4 - how to combine HtmlWebpackPlugin with split chunks?" Because chunk splitting usually means having multiple entry points, and the key problem is in HTML generation for this. Upvoted.

Comment: @EgorNepomnyaschih - it's not always for multiple entries, you'd wanna break your bundle into chunks in case it's too big regardless of the number of entries. and for a single entry the plugins work perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Version 4 of HtmlWebpackPlugin (which is alpha as of now) includes all entries' generated chunks automatically. So just setting `chunks: 'entry1'` should work:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'entry1.ejs',
    filename: 'entry1.html',
    chunks: ['entry1']
}),
```

... and leads to injecting of all dependent chunks in html file:

```
<script src="/vendors-entry1-entry2-entry3.js">
<script src="/vendors-entry1-entry3.js">
<script src="/entry1-entry2.js">
<script src="/entry1.js">
```

You can install it with

```
npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin@next
```

Comment: I'm using webpack 4.29.5 and it does not work exactly this way. It's still needed to specify which chunks to load like this: `chunks: ['vendors-entry1-entry2-entry3', 'vendors-entry1-entry3', 'entry1-entry2', 'entry1']`. Otherwise (like in the answer) it will load only the entry1.js file.

Comment: Just found that it's still planned for the @next release! https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1152

Comment: this doesn't work. It injects only once file which is the entry file but none of the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem and have had some minor success using a config setup I found [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points).  Not sure if it will apply to your specific use case, but I thought I'd share.

The optimization hash in webpack config looks like:

```
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    name: "commons",
                    chunks: "initial",
                    minChunks: 2,
                    minSize: 0
                }
            }
        },
        occurrenceOrder: true
    },
```

So using these entrypoints:

```
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js',
        home: './src/home.js',
        product: './src/product.js'
    }
```

And this as my HtmlWebpackPlugin setup:

```
    // base template common to all pages
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        inject: true,
        template: './src/jinja-templates/base.html.j2',
        filename: `${templates}/base.html.j2`,
        chunks: ['commons', 'app']
    }),

    // JUST the homepage
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        inject: true,
        template: './src/jinja-templates/index.html.j2',
        filename: `${templates}/index.html.j2`,
        chunks: ['home']
    }),

    // JUST the product template
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        inject: true,
        template: './src/jinja-templates/product.html.j2',
        filename: `${templates}/product.html.j2`,
        chunks: ['product']
    }),
```

I am successfully getting the "commons" and "app" chunks added to all pages, and on the homepage the "home" chunk (only) is added, and on the product page the "product" chunk (only) is added.  Here's an example of the source of the "home" page:

```
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/commons.7ca91fd78182a8eb23f6.js?7ca91fd78182a8eb23f6"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app.7ca91fd78182a8eb23f6.js?7ca91fd78182a8eb23f6"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/home.7ca91fd78182a8eb23f6.js?7ca91fd78182a8eb23f6"></script>
    </body>
```

I don't know if/how vendor modules can be split out using this setup.  I assume it's possible, but if so a secret cabal of webpack elites is keeping this information well-guarded :P

But given it's already splitting the code into several very small chunks I am not sure it's necessary (for me, anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I've actually ended up with a quite similar solution, unfortunately it's not really a solution as it does not scale for N entries and doesn't fully utilize the split chunks plugin

Comment: Regarding scalability, you can create a function that will create the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` for each entry, then use .concat(entryHtmlPlugins) to add them to the `plugins` array.